# R: Combining data.frames in a more elegant way

Tags: r

I'm building up a data frame based on random entries/rows. Here's the function that creates a random entry:

```
createRandomEntry <- function() {
    names <- c('Dilbert', 'Wally', 'Alice', 'Ashok', 'Topper')
    ages <- 30:45
    return(
        data.frame(
            Name = sample(names, 1),
            Age = sample(ages, 1),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )
}
```

Now I'm combining them to one big `data.frame` using this function:

```
createRandomEntries <- function(n) {
    df <- createRandomEntry()
    for (i in 2:n) {
        df <- rbind(df, createRandomEntry())
    }
    return(df)
}
```

Technically, it works well, but it's a bit clumsy for many reasons:

- I have to call the `createRandomEntry()` function at two places
- I have to use a loop

  - the loop has to start with index 2, since I already got the first entry
- Maybe calling `rbind` that often might be inefficient, I don't know...

In an earlier version, `createRandomEntry()` returned a `list` rather than a `data.frame`. Then I used `replicate()` to create a matrix, which first had to be transposed (by calling `t()` on it) in order to create a `data.frame` out of it. And that `data.frame` wasn't sortable (error: "unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'"). Calling `unlist()` on every row or returning a vector from `createRandomEntry()` would fix the sorting issues, but then I'd just get strings in every column.

There must be a better way. But how?

**Edit**: It's important to have a function that creates *one single entry*, because some of the values of an entry could be related to each other, like this enhanced function shows:

```
createRandomEntry <- function() {
    names <- c('Dilbert', 'Wally', 'Alice', 'Ashok', 'Topper')
    ages <- 30:45
    startedIn <- sample(1995:2005, 1)
    lostMotivation <- startedIn + sample(1:3, 1)
    return(
        data.frame(
            Name = sample(names, 1),
            Age = sample(ages, 1),
            StartYear = startedIn,
            LostMotivation = lostMotivation,
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )
}
createRandomEntries(3)
```

Which produces:

```
     Name Age StartYear LostMotivation
1   Ashok  42      1998           2000
2 Dilbert  43      1997           1999
3 Dilbert  30      1996           1999
```

Comment: `do.call('rbind.data.frame', lapply(1:100, function(i) createRandomEntry()))`

Comment: Think about `dplyr::rbind_list` and save each sample data frame into a list instead of overwriting your `data.frame` again and again.

Comment: @bouncyball, you beat me to it, probably `do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, createRandomEntry))` will work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move `n` from the second function to the first one?

```
createRandomEntries <- function(n) {
    names <- c('Dilbert', 'Wally', 'Alice', 'Ashok', 'Topper')
    ages <- 30:45
    return(
        data.frame(
            Name = sample(names, n, TRUE),
            Age = sample(ages, n, TRUE),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: It's indeed an option for this contrived example, but what if two fields of one entry would be related somehow to each other? Let's say I'd have a random date field "start" and another date field "end" with a certain amount of days added to it within a certain range. So there has to be a function that generates single entries.

Comment: If your problem is about dates just consider generate `start_date` and then add `end_date` using `merge` (which is a join-link function).
Otherwise @bouncyball solution should be fine!

Comment: Hm, probably I'm tackling R with too much of a C mindset, where operations cannot be applied that easily on whole sets of data...

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bruno Zamengo's answer, I've now rewritten the function:

```
createRandomEntries <- function(n) {
    names <- c('Dilbert', 'Wally', 'Alice', 'Ashok', 'Topper')
    ages <- 30:45
    df <- data.frame(
        Name = sample(names, n, replace = TRUE),
        Age = sample(ages, n, replace = TRUE),
        StartYear = sample(1995:2005, n, replace = TRUE),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    df$LostMotivation <- df$StartYear + sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)
    return(df)
}
```

However, I didn't use `merge`, as suggested.